# Unable to select first item of dynamically generated select with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically generating a select contol with jQuery on my page. The generated select is given below.

```
<select id="autoCompleteSelect" size="5" class="autoSelect">
    <option value="firstVal">firstVal</option>
    <option value="secondVal">secondVal</option>
</select>
```

Now i want to select the first item of this select control on my textbox keyup event. But i cannot do so. The keyup code is -

```
        $('#searchInput').keyup(function (e) {
            var a = $(".autoSelect").val();
            var myDDL = $('.autoSelect');
            myDDL[0].selectedIndex = 0;
        });
```

however when i do not generate select dynamically and just put it on the page from the beginning. Everything works fine. What could be the solution for dynamically generated select.

Comment: @Abhitalks how? can you please give the solution in an answer.

Comment: On second thoughts, I think I am unable to understand what exactly are you trying to do here? Could you add relevant markup to your question and explain a bit on what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

`$("#autoCompleteSelect").val($("#autoCompleteSelect option:first").val());`

http://jsfiddle.net/oob1ybxp/

Answer (score 1):

Keep your code in the form something like

```
 $('someStaticSelector').on('keyup', 'DynamicAddedSelector',  function (e) {
            var a = $(".autoSelect").val();
            var myDDL = $('.autoSelect');
            myDDL[0].selectedIndex = 0;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

If working with dynamically generated content, it is best to use [`event delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) concept like below:

```
// document here can be replaced with closest parent which 
// created/ existed without dynamic load
// provided context parameter to on function
$(document).on('keyup','#searchInput', function (e) {
   var a = $(".autoSelect").val();
   var myDDL = $('.autoSelect');
   myDDL[0].selectedIndex = 0;
});
```

Read this [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) also.